# How should I set constraint of UICollectionView in iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

Hi I want to put CollectionView in fullScreen
So I set it's constraint all top, buttom, left, right zero with SafeArea
But in iPhone 11, When I put many Items, CollectionView Cover the SafeArea with scroll
And I can't see last Item fully
I can see the Item when I scroll, but it bounce up immediately

When I set HeightConstraint with Constant, same height with SafeArea, It looks perfect
So I guess the reason of problem is that Height of SafeArea be changed when CollectionView require Scroll

Any Suggestion for this?
If I can, I want to solve it with StroyBoard

[image: Layout]

[image]

[image]

First screen is Auto Layout that I set on Storyboard

And Second One is current Work

I can't see the bottom of Last Cell , I can see if I scroll down, But It Bounce up like that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Some screen-caps showing the problem would help.

Comment: Please share some screenshots of what you are implementing through storyboard & the results.

Comment: @Suhail I added some screenshots , Thank you for caring

Comment: @Suhail The problem was header size that I defined was different with defined flowLayout.headerReferenceSize ! Thank you Very Much : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view hierarchy, I noticed a header view is residing for your collection view. Have your tried defining it's height using referenceSizeForHeaderInSection method? You will find that method in collectionViewLayout. Here's reference link :- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview